# where can I send free sms to hong kong

Tags: cellphones, china, internet

I know it's not a typical travel question

but I visit Hong Kong and want to send sms to people i meet there.

My provider charges almost 1 usd for each sms.

Used to use icq long time ago, but doesn't work on iphone

Tried few sites, but non of them worked.

http://www.freesmscraze.com/worldwide/send_free_sms_to_hong_kong/

http://smsfree4all.com/free-text-hong-kong.php

http://www.freebiesms.hk/CheckBackLink.aspx

http://dosms.me/send-free-sms-to-hong-kong.php

Anyone know of such?

Comment: Start using something like WhatsApp. Beyond that, I can't say this question is very on-topic and hence will be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you are not worried about using the web while in Hong Kong. So... use Skype. It won't be free, but it will be similarly priced to what it would cost if you had a local sim card.

Comment: including sms? I'm counting on wifi

Comment: Yep. Piece of cake.